# Angular 8 highcharts How to pass custom data to drilldown event in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular8, angular2-highcharts

I am new to Angular and was trying to implement below.
I have created a data object in Angular component

```
@..
...
export class MyComponent{
drilldownDataSeries : {
's1' : {
      ...
},
's2' : {
   ...
}
}
```

then want to use this object in drilldown event of chart object. Setting up the chart options in ngOnInit().

````
this.chartOptions = {
   chart :{
          events : {
drilldown : function(e){
 //** here i want to use drilldownDataSeries  object in the callback function
}
 }
}
}```

here i want to use drilldownDataSeries  object in the callback function.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to access *drilldownDataSeries* from the callback function, the easiest one is to use the **arrow function**. You can read more about this approach and about the other solutions in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/12285185

```js
...
     chart: {
           events: {
             drilldown: () => {
               console.log(this.drilldownData);
             }
           }
       },
...
```

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-jwwfd8